# Gradle init not using custom repo when converting maven project

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am trying to convert a maven project to gradle. Our maven project uses a custom repository for dependencies, and we can not download anything from ordinary repos. When running command

```
gradle init -I ./init.gradle
```

I am getting errors and I can see on the command line that it is trying to connect to the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. I have tried using the init.gradle script from userhome and gradlehome, but there was no change. I also added the custom repo to pom.xml since I saw someone say gradle uses those if available, but it didn't. This is my init.gradle for reference:

```
apply plugin: EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin

class EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin implements Plugin<Gradle> {

    void apply(Gradle gradle) {
        gradle.settingsEvaluated { settings ->
            settings.pluginManagement {
                repositories {
                    maven {
                      url "custom_repository_url"
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this at first:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
           mavenLocal()
           maven { url "custom_repository_url"}
        }
      } 
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
          url "custom_repository_url"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding a build.gradle with the following task and running it:

```
tasks.register('showRepos') {
    doLast {
        println "All repos:"
        println repositories.collect { it.name }
    }
}
```

This only printed out the custom repo. However deleting this and running gradle init still connects to the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

**Edit:**

It seems this question won't be solved. In case you found this when looking for an answer, I have found this solution that might work for you. I wasn't so lucky.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19884

I have also crated an issue on github. Maybe there will be an answer there.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/1097

Comment: Normally, Gradle would try to find things it searches for in all repos configured. Can you see what exactly the error is and what Gradle is searching for? Does it even try with your custom url and then look into `repo.maven.org` (or the other way round)? Perhaps it's searching for something not contained in your custum repo?

Comment: From the logs, I can say that it is only trying to connect https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and not my custom repo. All the jars are in our custom repo as we do not have access to any other repositories. I have checked again, just to be sure, and also maven can download them just fine.

Comment: I see. Sorry, then I have no more ideas at the moment, I hope, that someone else can help you.